# Clang+VS2013: error when including c++ header (vs2012:working)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, clang, visual-studio-2013

**Edit**

i found http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html

> Because of this, clang cannot parse the C++ standard library included
>   with Visual Studio, nor parts of the Windows Platform SDK.

So, if C++ is not supported with Visual Studio headers, should i still write a bug report?

**Q:**

I installed the clang visual studio toolchain from http://llvm.org/builds/.
Using VS2013, i get several errors when compiling any c++ header.
For example:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

These errors seem to be related to microsofts c++14 implementation.
This does NOT occur in Visual Studio 2012.
Switching to the Toolchain **LLVM-vs2012** in VS2013 also works

**Errors with VS2013+LLVM-vs2013:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/ZI'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Gm'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/EHsc'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/GS'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/fp:precise'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Ycstdafx.h'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/FpDebug\ConsoleApplication1.pch'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/FdDebug\vc120.pdb'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Gd'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/ZI'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Gm'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/EHsc'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/GS'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/fp:precise'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Yustdafx.h'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/FpDebug\ConsoleApplication1.pch'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/FdDebug\vc120.pdb'
1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Gd'
1>  In file included from ConsoleApplication1.cpp:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\memory:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0:9:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xutility:8:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\utility:8:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(620,32): error : '_Ty' does not refer to a value
1>                  : _Cat_base<_IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(_Ty, _Args...)>
1>                                                ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(617,15) :  note: declared here
1>  template<class _Ty,
1>                 ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(621,1): error : expected class name
1>          {       // determine whether _Ty(_Args...) is constructible
1>          ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(746,19): error : '_Ty' does not refer to a value
1>                  _IS_DESTRUCTIBLE(_Ty)
1>                                   ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(48,31) :  note: expanded from macro '_IS_DESTRUCTIBLE'
1>          : _Cat_base<__is_destructible(_Ty)>
1>                                        ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(744,15) :  note: declared here
1>  template<class _Ty>
1>                 ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(747,1): error : expected class name
1>          {       // determine whether _Ty has a destructor
1>          ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(887,40): error : '_Ty' does not refer to a value
1>                  : _Cat_base<_IS_NOTHROW_CONSTRUCTIBLE(_Ty, _Args...)>
1>                                                        ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(884,15) :  note: declared here
1>  template<class _Ty,
1>                 ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(888,1): error : expected class name
1>          {       // determine whether _Ty(_Args...) is nothrow constructible
1>          ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(951,25): error : '_To' does not refer to a value
1>                  _IS_NOTHROW_ASSIGNABLE(_To, _From)
1>                                         ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(50,37) :  note: expanded from macro '_IS_NOTHROW_ASSIGNABLE'
1>          : _Cat_base<__is_nothrow_assignable(_To, _From)>
1>                                              ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(947,15) :  note: declared here
1>  template<class _To,
1>                 ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(953,1): error : expected class name
1>          {       // determine whether _From can be assigned to _To, nothrow
1>          ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(1000,27): error : '_Ty' does not refer to a value
1>                  _IS_NOTHROW_DESTRUCTIBLE(_Ty)
1>                                           ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(52,39) :  note: expanded from macro '_IS_NOTHROW_DESTRUCTIBLE'
1>          : _Cat_base<__is_nothrow_destructible(_Ty)>
1>                                                ^
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(997,15) :  note: declared here
1>  template<class _Ty>
1>                 ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(1002,1): error : expected class name
1>          {       // determine whether _Ty has a nothrow destructor
1>          ^
1>  10 errors generated.
```

running `clang -v` on the command line outputs

```
clang version 3.4 (195641)
Target: i686-pc-win32
Thread model: posix
```

Can any of you reproduce this error? If yes, i would create a bugreport at http://llvm.org/bugs/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is being tracked here: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17926

See the comment section for further info.